# How to disable Auto - Keyframing in Blender 2.8

Tags: animation

Yesterday Blender 2.8 was released and it was exciting for me. But when I move the objects in the viewport, a keyframe gets added, which is quite annoying. Could someone tell me how to turn this off? Thanks in advance (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to deactivate the *Automatic Keyframe Insertio*n button:

[image]